# Branch sub-folder from trunk

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

let suppose, in trunk we have a folder with below hierarchy;

```
Code
  Server Code
  Client Code
  Helper Apps
```

So, if a developer just need to do a change to `Client Code`, is it alright for him to **branch** only **this folder** and then **merge** it back to **trunk** when done?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that is possible. In subversion there is one rule: "a folder is folder is a folder". Meaning "trunk" or "branches" or "subfeaturetestspike12" are just folders to subversion. You can do everything with any folder - they don't differ. Even the "tags" is just a folder. Usually you have to do something to prevent commits in here.

So in your case you could only copy (or branch) the client code folder and then merge later. Or create a new folder, copy one file from client code and have a branch of only one file. Subversion makes not much of a difference - since a folder is folder... and so on. A merge is essentially repeating changes from one branch (folder) to another.

Keep in mind that creating a partial branch may be a bit dangerous when merging - as the branch did not fully build the whole thing but only parts of it. There are some practices at Apache for example: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html

Comment: If I go for creating the branch of entire trunk, would space be an issue or SVN just keep track of files which changes and doesn't make a whole new copy?

Comment: No space is not an issue. Subversion makes lazy copies when creating branches (or copies of folders). Probably an additional 4 kB per branch. It is also very fast since it only creates a new reference (Of course: if people checkout the trunk and re-commit it elsewhere: that will create a complete new copy).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. One have another question. So, if lets say we have a folder Code and within it we have two folders Helper Apps and Client Code, is it recommended/acceptable that I create trunk and branches folders for each folder i.e. Helper Apps and Client Code?